# Operating with oracle queries (multiply, divide, etc)

Tags: oracle

I have these this query (oracle), I need to operate with the result and then apply the AVG, so it would be AVG((result*7)/40)

I have tried wrapping it in parenthesis etc, but it won't work.

```
SELECT
((fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date))-(fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Submit_Date)))
FROM CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE
WHERE  fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date) 
BETWEEN  '01-01-2015'  AND  '31-01-2015'
AND 
((fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date))-(fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Submit_Date))) < (SELECT 
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.95) within group (order by(( fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date) )-( fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Submit_Date) )))
FROM CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE WHERE  fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date)
BETWEEN  '01-01-2015'  AND  '31-01-2015')
```

This is what I've tried

```
AVG((SELECT
((fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date))-(fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Submit_Date)))
FROM CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE
WHERE  fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date) 
BETWEEN  '01-01-2015'  AND  '31-01-2015'
AND 
((fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date))-(fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Submit_Date))) < (SELECT 
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.95) within group (order by(( fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date) )-( fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Submit_Date) )))
FROM CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE WHERE  fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date)
BETWEEN  '01-01-2015'  AND  '31-01-2015'))*7)/40)
```

And I'm getting a SQLSyntaxErrorException ORA-00900

Comment: First and foremost - what error message are you getting? Second - where is the calculation in your query? it's supposed to work fine, but I can't see the operation in your query.

Comment: Edited it. :) Thanks in advanced for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your original query runs correctly, this is the correct way to wrap your query -

```
select (avg(fn_value)*7)/40 FROM (
SELECT
((fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date))-(fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Submit_Date))) as fn_value
FROM CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE
WHERE  fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date) 
BETWEEN  '01-01-2015'  AND  '31-01-2015'
AND 
((fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date))-(fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Submit_Date))) < (SELECT 
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.95) within group (order by(( fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date) )-( fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Submit_Date) )))
FROM CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE WHERE  fn_adjusted_date(CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE.Completed_Date)
BETWEEN  '01-01-2015'  AND  '31-01-2015'))
```

Notice I took the original query, wrapped it up in parenthesis and the selected the outcome from the original query. The outcome of this can go through any mathematical operation you like.